# Transpose many aggregates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables, `cases`, my main table, and `activities`, which shows work being done against certain cases.

```
CREATE TABLE cases
    ([caseno] int, [case_detail] varchar(8), [date_received] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO cases
    ([caseno], [case_detail], [date_received])
VALUES
    (1, 'DETAIL A', '2018-04-01 00:00:00'),
    (2, 'DETAIL B', '2018-05-01 00:00:00'),
    (3, 'DETAIL C', '2018-06-01 00:00:00')
;

CREATE TABLE activities
    ([caseno] int, [activity] int, [team] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO activities
    ([caseno], [activity], [team])
VALUES
    (1, 00, 'A'),
    (1, 10, 'A'),
    (1, 00, 'A'),
    (1, 00, 'B'),
    (1, 90, 'C'),
    (1, 00, 'C'),
    (1, 00, 'A'),
    (2, 10, 'A'),
    (2, 00, 'A'),
    (2, 00, 'B'),
    (3, 90, 'C'),
    (3, 00, 'C')
;
```

I'm interested in aggregating the `activities` data, for `activity = '00'`, split by `team`, and attaching to the `cases` data.

I've achieved this in the following way but I suspect it is not optimal. The cases table is about 1million rows and activities table is 200million rows or so.

```
SELECT T.*, A.A, B.B, C.C FROM cases T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT caseno, COUNT(*) AS A FROM activities WHERE activity = '00' AND team = 'A' GROUP BY caseno) A ON T.[caseno] = A.[caseno]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT caseno, COUNT(*) AS B FROM activities WHERE activity = '00' AND team = 'B' GROUP BY caseno) B ON T.[caseno] = B.[caseno]
LEFT JOIN (SELECT caseno, COUNT(*) AS C FROM activities WHERE activity = '00' AND team = 'C' GROUP BY caseno) C ON T.[caseno] = C.[caseno]
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=92632c9af821935790a7986e6f654b13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pivot solution

```
select *
from 
  ( select cs.*,A.team 
    from cases cs 
    join activities a on cs.caseno=a.caseno and a.activity = 00 
  ) C
pivot 
  (count(team)
   for team in ([A],[B],[C])  
  ) pvt
```

give us same result

[sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=20437458ec19f1b76098a9a245500ce2)

Answer (score 4):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT c.caseno, case_detail, date_received,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS a,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS b,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS c
FROM cases c
LEFT JOIN activities a
  ON c.caseno = a.caseno
 AND a.activity = '00'
GROUP BY c.caseno, case_detail, date_received;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e6cca3114aea047767b16af2dfef38d)**

---

**EDIT**

Without typing all columns in `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH cte AS (
 SELECT c.caseno,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'A' THEN 1 END) AS a,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'B' THEN 1 END) AS b,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN team = 'C' THEN 1 END) AS c
 FROM cases c
 LEFT JOIN activities a
   ON c.caseno = a.caseno
  AND a.activity = '00'
 GROUP BY c.caseno   -- only PK
)
SELECT * FROM cte JOIN cases c ON cte.caseno = c.caseno;
```

Comment: `CASE` is a reserved word `FROM [case] C ...`

Comment: @Sami Yes, table is called cases(I fixed it)

Comment: Good idea - however in reality my `cases` table is actually quite long, so would require calling lots of variables into the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Ross We have year 2018, just drag and drop column list from SSMS Object explorer to SQL editor pane(no need to manually type them). Plus `SELECT *` is antipattern.

Comment: Besides the typing, does calling many fields into the `GROUP BY` not have performance implications?

Comment: @Ross Sure, but how else do you expect to aggregate across so many columns? If performance of this query is a bigger concern than whatever drove this design, then perhaps you should revisit the design and store the data in such a way that better suits this query.

Comment: @Ross Yes, it could have impact. But if your column list contain unique column query optimizer should handle it smoothly.

Comment: Appreciate the advice! Wish I could have influence over the data structure but unfortunately that's not the case here.